# How to poll and keep track of external job status through Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I am working on polling `boto3` to check the status of a SageMaker Autopilot job using Airflow. I am using a `PythonSensor` to wait for the status to return `Completed` for both `JobStatus` and `JobSecondaryStatus`, then end the entire pipeline. These are the values that they can contain which I made enums of in the code:

```py
'AutoMLJobStatus': 'Completed'|'InProgress'|'Failed'|'Stopped'|'Stopping',
'AutoMLJobSecondaryStatus': 'Starting'|'AnalyzingData'|'FeatureEngineering'|'ModelTuning'|'MaxCandidatesReached'|'Failed'|'Stopped'|'MaxAutoMLJobRuntimeReached'|'Stopping'|'CandidateDefinitionsGenerated'|'GeneratingExplainabilityReport'|'Completed'|'ExplainabilityError'|'DeployingModel'|'ModelDeploymentError'
```

`_sagemaker_job_status` takes `automl_job_name` through xcom from an upstream task and it successfully gets passed. With this job name I can pass it to [descibe_auto_ml_job()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.describe_auto_ml_job) to get the status through `AutoMLJobStatus` and `AutoMLJobSecondaryStatus`.

The main point of this is for messaging through Slack to see all the unique stages the job is at. Currently, I am trying to save all the unique job statuses to a set and then checking that set before sending a message with the job statuses in it.

But everytime `_sagemaker_job_status` is poked, the values of the set seem to be the same therefore sending a slack message everytime the function is poked, I logged the sets and both are empty. Below this I made a simpler example that worked.

```py
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.python import PythonSensor
import boto3


def _sagemaker_job_status(templates_dict, **context):
    """
    Checks the SageMaker AutoMLJobStatus and AutoMLJobSecondaryStatus
    for updates and when both are complete the entire process is marked as
    successful
    """
    automl_job_name = templates_dict.get("automl_job_name")
    if not automl_job_name:
        error_message = "AutoMLJobName was not passed from upstream"
        print(error_message)
        task_fail_slack_alert(
            context=context,
            extra_message=error_message,
        )
    client = boto3.client("sagemaker", "us-east-1")
    response = client.describe_auto_ml_job(
        AutoMLJobName=automl_job_name,
    )
    job_status = response.get("AutoMLJobStatus")
    secondary_job_status = response.get("AutoMLJobSecondaryStatus")
    past_job_statuses = set()
    past_secondary_job_statuses = set()
    print(f"Past Job Statuses : {past_job_statuses}")
    print(f"Past Secondary Job Statuses : {past_secondary_job_statuses}")
    # If the job status has not been already seen
    if (
        job_status not in past_job_statuses
        and secondary_job_status not in past_secondary_job_statuses
    ):
        message = f"""
            JobStatus : {job_status}
            JobSecondaryStatus : {secondary_job_status}
            """
        print(message)
        task_success_slack_alert(
            context=context,
            extra_message=message,
        )
    past_job_statuses.add(job_status)
    past_secondary_job_statuses.add(secondary_job_status)
    # If the main job fails
    if job_status == JobStatus.Failed.value: 
        error_message = "SageMaker Autopilot Job Failed!"
        task_fail_slack_alert(
            context=context,
            extra_message=error_message,
        )
        raise AirflowFailException(error_message)
    
    return (
        job_status == JobStatus.Completed.value 
        and secondary_job_status == JobSecondaryStatus.Completed.value
    )

args = {
    "owner": "Yudhiesh",
    "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    "schedule_interval": "@once",
    "on_failure_callback": task_fail_slack_alert,
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="02_lasic_retraining_sagemaker_autopilot",
    default_args=args,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:

    sagemaker_job_status = PythonSensor(
        task_id="sagemaker_job_status",
        python_callable=_sagemaker_job_status,
        templates_dict={
            "automl_job_name": "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='train_model_sagemaker_autopilot')}}",  # noqa: E501
        },
    )

    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id="end",
    )

    sagemaker_job_status >> end
```

I created a similar setup as before but this time I randomly generated the values from an enum of `JobStatus` & `JobSecondaryStatus` and tried to only print the values if they are unique, and turns out it works perfectly. Could anyone explain why this happens and what I can do to the main example to get it to work?

```
import airflow
import random
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.sensors.python import PythonSensor
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException

def _mimic_sagemaker_job_status():
    job_statuses = [status.value for status in JobStatus]
    job_secondary_statuses = [
        secondary_status.value for secondary_status in JobSecondaryStatus
    ]
    past_job_statuses = set()
    past_secondary_job_statuses = set()
    job_status = random.choice(job_statuses)
    job_secondary_status = random.choice(job_secondary_statuses)
    if (
        job_status not in past_job_statuses
        and job_secondary_status not in past_secondary_job_statuses
    ):
        message = f"""
            JobStatus : {job_status}
            JobSecondaryStatus : {job_secondary_status}
            """
        # Send alerts on every new job status update
        print(message)
    past_job_statuses.add(job_status)
    past_secondary_job_statuses.add(job_secondary_status)
    if (
        job_status == JobStatus.Failed.value
        or job_secondary_status == JobSecondaryStatus.Failed.value
    ):
        raise AirflowFailException("SageMaker Autopilot Job Failed!")

    return (
        job_secondary_status == JobSecondaryStatus.Completed.value
        and job_status == JobStatus.Completed.value
    )


with DAG(
    dag_id="04_sagemaker_sensor",
    start_date=airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(3),
    schedule_interval="@once",
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:

    wait_for_status = PythonSensor(
        task_id="wait_for_status",
        python_callable=_mimic_sagemaker_job_status,
        dag=dag,
    )

    end = DummyOperator(
        task_id="end",
    )

    wait_for_status >> end
```

Enums used in the above code:

```
from enum import Enum

class JobStatus(Enum):
    """
    Enum of all the potential values of a SageMaker Autopilot job status
    """

    Completed = "Completed"
    InProgress = "InProgress"
    Failed = "Failed"
    Stopped = "Stopped"
    Stopping = "Stopping"


class JobSecondaryStatus(Enum):
    """
    Enum of all the potential values of a SageMaker Autopilot job secondary
    status
    """

    Starting = "Starting"
    AnalyzingData = "AnalyzingData"
    FeatureEngineering = "FeatureEngineering"
    ModelTuning = "ModelTuning"
    MaxCandidatesReached = "MaxCandidatesReached"
    Failed = "Failed"
    Stopped = "Stopped"
    MaxAutoMLJobRuntimeReached = "MaxAutoMLJobRuntimeReached"
    Stopping = "Stopping"
    CandidateDefinitionsGenerated = "CandidateDefinitionsGenerated"
    GeneratingExplainabilityReport = "GeneratingExplainabilityReport"
    Completed = "Completed"
    ExplainabilityError = "ExplainabilityError"
    DeployingModel = "DeployingModel"
    ModelDeploymentError = "ModelDeploymentError"
```

#### EDIT:

I suppose another work around for the main example would be to have an operator create a temporary file containing JSON of the set before the sagemaker job status, then within the sagemaker job status I can check the job statuses saved to the file and then print them if they are unique. I just realised that I can make use of the database as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So  I couldn't seem to get it working as it is so I resorted to creating a JSON file that stores the different SageMaker Autopilot job statuses which I read and write to in the PythonSensor.

This takes in the AutoMLJobName from the previous step, creates a temporary file of the job statuses, and returns the AutoMLJobName and the name of the JSON file.

```py
import tempfile

def _create_job_status_json(templates_dict, **context):
    automl_job_name = templates_dict.get("sagemaker_autopilot_data_paths")
    if not automl_job_name:
        error_message = "AutoMLJobName was not passed from upstream"
        print(error_message)
        task_fail_slack_alert(
            context=context,
            extra_message=error_message,
        )
    initial = {
        "JobStatus": [],
        "JobSecondaryStatus": [],
    }
    file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False)
    json.dump({"Status": initial}, file)
    file.flush()
    return (file.name, automl_job_name)
```

Next this function reads the JSON file based on the name and then checks the different job statuses based on the boto3 sagemaker client. If the main job fails then the whole run fails. It adds the job statuses to a dictionary if one of them are unique. Once that is done it will write the dictionary to the JSON file. When the entire job finishes, it sends some details about the  best model as a Slack message. It returns `true` when both job statuses are `Completed`. Just a note, I also removed the JSON file if the job is successfull or if it fails.

```py
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException
import boto3

def _sagemaker_job_status(templates_dict, **context):
    """
    Checks the SageMaker AutoMLJobStatus and AutoMLJobSecondaryStatus
    for updates and when both are complete the entire process is marked as
    successful
    """
    file_name, automl_job_name = templates_dict.get("automl_job_data")
    job_status_dict = {}
    client = boto3.client("sagemaker", "us-east-1")
    if not client:
        raise AirflowFailException(
            "Unable to get access to boto3 sagemaker client",
        )
    with open(file_name, "r") as json_file:
        response = client.describe_auto_ml_job(
            AutoMLJobName=automl_job_name,
        )
        job_status = response.get("AutoMLJobStatus")
        secondary_job_status = response.get("AutoMLJobSecondaryStatus")
        job_status_dict = json.load(json_file)
        status = job_status_dict.get("Status")
        past_job_statuses = status.get("JobStatus")
        past_secondary_job_statuses = status.get("JobSecondaryStatus")
        if job_status == JobStatus.Failed.value:
            error_message = "SageMaker Autopilot Job Failed!"
            task_fail_slack_alert(
                context=context,
                extra_message=error_message,
            )
            os.remove(file_name)
            raise AirflowFailException(error_message)
        if (
            job_status not in past_job_statuses
            or secondary_job_status not in past_secondary_job_statuses
        ):
            message = f"""
                JobStatus : {job_status}
                JobSecondaryStatus : {secondary_job_status}
                """
            print(message)
            task_success_slack_alert(
                context=context,
                extra_message=message,
            )
            past_job_statuses.append(job_status)
            past_secondary_job_statuses.append(secondary_job_status)

    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
        json.dump(job_status_dict, file)

        if (
            job_status == JobStatus.Completed.value
            and secondary_job_status == JobSecondaryStatus.Completed.value
        ):
            os.remove(file_name)
            response = client.describe_auto_ml_job(
                AutoMLJobName=automl_job_name,
            )
            best_candidate = response.get("BestCandidate")
            best_candidate_id = best_candidate.get("CandidateName")
            best_metric_name = (
                best_candidate.get("FinalAutoMLJobObjectiveMetric")
                .get("MetricName")
                .split(":")[1]
                .upper()
            )
            best_metric_value = round(
                best_candidate.get("FinalAutoMLJobObjectiveMetric").get(
                    "Value",
                ),
                3,
            )
            message = f"""
                Best Candidate ID : {best_candidate_id}
                Best Candidate Metric Score : {best_metric_value}{best_metric_name}
            """  # noqa: E501
            task_success_slack_alert(
                context=context,
                extra_message=message,
            )

        return (
            job_status == JobStatus.Completed.value
            and secondary_job_status == JobSecondaryStatus.Completed.value
        )
```

DAG code:

```py
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.python import PythonSensor

args = {
    "owner": "Yudhiesh",
    "start_date": airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    "schedule_interval": "@once",
    "on_failure_callback": task_fail_slack_alert,
}

with DAG(
    dag_id="02_lasic_retraining_sagemaker_autopilot",
    default_args=args,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:


    create_job_status_json = PythonOperator(
        task_id="create_job_status_json",
        python_callable=_create_job_status_json,
        templates_dict={
            "sagemaker_autopilot_data_paths": "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='train_model_sagemaker_autopilot')}}",  # noqa: E501
        },
    )

    sagemaker_job_status = PythonSensor(
        task_id="sagemaker_job_status",
        python_callable=_sagemaker_job_status,
        templates_dict={
            "automl_job_data": "{{task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='create_job_status_json')}}",  # noqa: E501
        },
    )
    # train_model_sagemaker_autopilot is not included but it initiates the training through boto3
    train_model_sagemaker_autopilot >> create_job_status_json

    create_job_status_json >> sagemaker_job_status
```